# NSubstitute - setting a property of the calling object

Tags: moq, nsubstitute

I have a in issue where I would like to swap out Moq for NSubstitute entirely.  In most cases, this is extremely straightforward, however I have run across a fairly specialized issue.

Here's the Moq code.

```
_registrationCommandHandler.Setup(c => c.Execute
(It.Is<CheckUniqueUserCommand>(r => r.Request.UserName == "fred"))).
                Callback((CheckUniqueUserCommand c) =>
                {
                    c.Response = new CheckUserNameIsUniqueResponse()
                    {
                        IsUnique = true,
                        Success = true
                    };
                    c.Success = true;
                });
```

The closest I seem to be able to get with NSubstitute is

```
 _registrationCommandHandler.When(c => c.Execute    
(Arg.Any<CheckUniqueUserCommand>())).Do
            ((CheckUniqueUserCommand c) =>
            {
              c.Response = new __Internal.CheckUserNameIsUniqueResponse()
              {
                  IsUnique = true,
                  Success = true
              };
            c.Success = true;
          });
```

which won't even compile.  This leaves me a bit stuck.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here, but try:

```
 _registrationCommandHandler
    .When(c => c.Execute(Arg.Is<CheckUniqueUserCommand>(r => r.Request.UserName == "fred")))
    .Do(call => {
          var c = call.Arg<CheckUniqueUserCommand>();
          c.Response = new __Internal.CheckUserNameIsUniqueResponse()
          {
              IsUnique = true,
              Success = true
          };
          c.Success = true;
    });
```

NSubstitute does not do the same argument passing as [Moq does for callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks). Instead it passes a parameter with information about the call, and you can [access the arguments using `call.Arg<T>` or `call[i]`](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/#call_information).

In addition to changing the `.Do` block, I also switched from using `Arg.Any(..)` to `Arg.Is(..)` to closer match the Moq sample.

Hope this helps.